# Error 1064 in a stored procedure in MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I am using MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE and i'm trying to create a stored procedure to show 2 fields from my table. I am receiving the following error:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE student (
 id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 name VARCHAR(200),
 age INT,
 final_grade DOUBLE,
 sex VARCHAR(1)
)
```

And this is the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE show_name_grade () 
 BEGIN
  SELECT name,final_grade FROM student;
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to redefine Delimiter to something else other than `;`. At the end, define it back to `;`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE show_name_grade () 
 BEGIN
  SELECT name,final_grade FROM student;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: the same issue appears on Mysql's sqaila db.